# how create <TouchableNativeFeedback /> with ( NATIVE ) Ripple effect

Tags: react-native, ripple

my question is about (TouchableNativeFeedback) [[RectNativeComponent]]  method

in react Native Document , facebook say

```
static Ripple(color: string, borderless: boolean)
```

### i want know how implement this and where must be called

| ReactNative :: 0.55.4 |
| Platform :: Android . |

---

Facebook Document :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#ripple

Comment: I added a live example with expo. If that helped you push the green tick.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you use methods of a component in react native.

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#EEE')}>
  <View style={{ width: undefined, padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#000' }}>
    <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'center' }}>Button</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Specify your favourite colour I gave green as an example

Expo [Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/BJ0Mdy_pH)

Reference [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html)

Comment: hi @RaajNadar , thank to answer my question ,  i am tested this snippet in my Emulation , but , not anything happen ( Ripple UI)

Comment: You are using EXPO?